# Rails 3 load method before filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, before-filter

What is the reason for using a `before_filter :load`?

```
def load
  @posts = Post.all
  @post = Post.new
end
```

What does this accomplish? I've just seen it done in a tutorial and don't understand if it's beneficial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case the load method will be called for all method calls within the controller. Meaning `@posts` and `@post` will be available to all actions for said controller. It is very rare that I use them. Just calling `load` within the action that needs it and moving the load method to private should be good enough.

If you wanted `@posts` and `@post` to be available for all the actions in the controller then this is an acceptable solution.

You could always do `before_filter :load, only: [:index]`

Comment: So it's just a quick method to reduce redundancy? Does it help with load time or anything like that?

Comment: If anything I would say it increases load slightly but not to a point you will ever notice.